# invalid column name with getstring(column name) on stored proc cursor return

Tags: java, oracle

I have a simple stored proc:

```
SELECT NVL(pnum,0)
      INTO emp_pnum 
      FROM employee_pnum 
     WHERE person_id = i_person_id
       AND pn_status_id = (SELECT pn_status_id FROM ems.pn_status WHERE pn_status_desc = 'Active');

SELECT NVL(pnum,0)
      INTO old_pnum 
      FROM employee_pnum_history
     WHERE person_id = i_person_id    
       AND created_date = (SELECT MAX(created_date) FROM ems.employee_pnum_history WHERE person_id = i_person_id);

OPEN x_pnum_history
   FOR SELECT emp_pnum,old_pnum
         FROM dual;
```

So cursor `x_pnum_history` is returned. All I want is to read the resultset in to a class as follows

```
EmployeePNum empPnum = new EmployeePNum();
empPnum.setCurrent_pnum(rs.getString("emp_pnum"));
empPnum.setOld_pnum(rs.getString("old_pnum"));
```

It says

```
CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call EMS.EMS_PKG.GET_EMP_PNUM(?, ?, ?, ?)}];
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

I am not sure what exactly is wrong here...any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if the column names are upper-case in the `getString()` calls? I'm pretty sure that's case-sensitive but can't check right now...

Comment: I tried changing them to upper case. Its the same error. Exception is caught at "empPnum.setCurrent_pnum(rs.getString("emp_pnum"));"

Comment: It works fine when i have it like this "empPnum.setCurrent_pnum(rs.getString(0));"

Comment: Sorry i meant "empPnum.setCurrent_pnum(rs.getString(1));"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```sql
OPEN x_pnum_history
   FOR SELECT emp_pnum,old_pnum
         FROM dual;
```

... you're selecting the values from the PL/SQL block's scope, but the columns you're generating have no names. You can see something similar with this (run through SQL Developer):

```
var rc refcursor

declare
  emp_pnum number;
begin
  emp_pnum := 1;
  open :rc for select emp_pnum as emp_pnum from dual;
end;
/

anonymous block completed

print rc

RC
---------------------------------------
:B1                                     
--------------------------------------- 
1
```

Note the column header shows a generic bind marker, `:B1`. But if I explicitly alias the columns then that carries through:

```
declare
  emp_pnum number;
begin
  emp_pnum := 1;
  open :rc for select emp_pnum as emp_pnum from dual;
end;
/

anonymous block completed

print rc

RC
---------------------------------------
EMP_PNUM                                
--------------------------------------- 
1
```

So in your case you'd need to change your procedure to include aliases:

```
OPEN x_pnum_history
   FOR SELECT emp_pnum as emp_pnum, old_pnum as old_pnum
         FROM dual;
```

Of course, that assumes your driver and version can handle named parameters. I think you still probably need to user uppercase names in your `getString()` calls too though.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks Alex. Will try this out and let you know. Thanks once again.

Comment: That works..I am using uppercase names as well. Thank you for explaining in detail.